# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to convert [okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part@xxx] to RequestBody

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using formData to send a list of images captured on local devices to the server.

```html
import okhttp3.MediaType
import okhttp3.MultipartBody
import okhttp3.RequestBody
import retrofit.Callback
import retrofit.Response
import retrofit.Retrofit
import Reception.PurchaseOrderMarkAsReceivedResponse

   @Subscribe
    fun onMarkPurchaseOrderAsReceived(event: MarkReceptionAsReceivedEvent) {

        try {
            val parts = ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>()
            for (file in event.files) {
                val requestFile: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file)
                val part: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, requestFile)
                parts.add(part)
            }


            mApi.markPurchaseOrderAsReceive(parts, event.id).enqueue(object : Callback<PurchaseOrderMarkAsReceivedResponse>{
                override fun onResponse(
                    response: Response<PurchaseOrderMarkAsReceivedResponse>?,
                    retrofit: Retrofit?
                ) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        if (response.isSuccess && response.body() != null) {
                            log(Log.INFO, "Successful import image files")
                            bus.post(MarkReceptionAsReceivedSuccessEvent(response.body().purchaseOrder))
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(t: Throwable?) {
                    log(Log.INFO, "Failed")
                }

            })
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e("errorr", e.toString())
        }

    }
```

This is how I invoke the function markPurchaseOrderAsReceive:

```html
import retrofit.http.Multipart
import retrofit.http.Part
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
import okhttp3.MultipartBody
import retrofit.Call

 @Multipart
    @POST(Constants.Urls.MARK_AS_RECEIVED)
    fun markPurchaseOrderAsReceive(
        @Part("document[]") files: List<MultipartBody.Part>,
        @Path("id") id: Int): Call<PurchaseOrderMarkAsReceivedResponse>
```

However, I always get this error in onFailure : "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to convert [okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part@xxx] to RequestBody"

In build.gradle

```html
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
```